# Limit output of all Linux commands

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for a way to limit the amount of output produced by all command line programs in Linux, and preferably tell me when it is limited.

I'm working over a server which has a lag on the display. Occasionally I will accidentally run a command which outputs a large amount of text to the terminal, such as `cat` on a large file or `ls` on a directory with many files. I then have to wait a while for all the output to be printed to the terminal.

So is there a way to automatically pipe all output into a command like `head` or `wc` to prevent too much output having to be printed to terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the general case, but for each well-known command (cat, ls, find?)
you could do the following:

- hardlink a copy to the existing utility
- write a tiny bash function that calls the utility and pipes to head (or wc, or whatever)
- alias the name of the utility to call your function.

So along these lines (utterly untested):

```
$ ln `which cat` ~/bin/old_cat

function trunc_cat () {
   `old_cat $@ | head -n 100`
}

alias cat=trunc_cat
```

Comment: yeah I'd thought of something like that, but was hoping for something more general

Answer (score 1):

Making aliases of all your commands would be a good start. Something like

```
alias lm="ls -al | more"
alias cam="cat $@ | more"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) could help?

Comment: I use byobu, I still have to wait for all the output to display though. Is there something in this I'm unaware of that would help?

Comment: Press Ctrl+A Esc and the terminal will freeze at the current location. You can skip to the end with Esc >.

Answer (score 1):

this makes me think of bash-completion.

As `complete` command in bash enables you to specify handler when a program is not found,

what about write your own handler and clear `$PATH`, in order to execute every command with redirection to a filtering pipe?

#Did not try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working over a network connection, like ssh, into a remote server then try piping the output of the command to `less`. That way you can manage and navigate the output from the program on the server better. Use 'j' and 'k' to move up and down per line and 'ctrl-u' and 'ctrl-d' to move 1/2 a page up and down. When you do this only the relevant text (i.e. what fits on the screen) will be transmitted over the network.

Comment: I was looking for something more automatic than having to always pipe to less. This also has the problem of opening `less` for small amounts of output and losing colourisation for e.g. `ls`.