# How to limit output from a potentially too verbose command?

Tags: bash, stdout

I am looking for a bash snippet for limiting the amount of console output from a shell command that could potentially become too verbose.

The purpose of this is for usage in build/CI environments where you do want to limit the amount out console output in order to prevent overloading the CI server (or even client tailing the output).

Full requirements:

- display only up to 100 lines from the top (head) of the command output
- display only up to 100 lines from the bottom (tail) of the command output
- archive both `stdout` and `stderr` in full into a `command.log.gz` file
- console output must be displayed relatively in realtime, a solution that output the result at the end is not acceptable as we need to be able to see its execution progress.

Current findings

- `unbuffer` could be used to force the stdout/stderr to be unbuffered
- `|& tee` can be used to send output to both archiver and tail/head
- `|& gzip --stdout >command.log.gz` could archive the console output
- `head -n100` and `tail -n100` can be used to limit the console output they introduce at least some problems like undesired results if number of output lines is under 200.

Comment: `[ -f command.log.gz ] && gunzip command.log.gz; somecommand > tmp && (( $(wc -l <tmp) > 100 )) && { head -n100 tmp; tail -n100 tmp; } || cat tmp; cat tmp >> command.log; gzip command.log; rm tmp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit output of all Linux commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8335425/608639)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you need to do limit output online (while it's being generated).
Here is a function that I can think of that would be useful for you.

```
limit_output() {
    FullLogFile="./output.log"  # Log file to keep the input content
    typeset -i MAX=15   # number or lines from head, from tail
    typeset -i LINES=0  # number of lines displayed

    # tee will save the copy of the input into a log file
    tee "$FullLogFile" | {
        # The pipe will cause this part to be executed in a subshell
        # The command keeps LINES from losing it's value before if
        while read -r Line; do
            if [[ $LINES -lt $MAX ]]; then
                LINES=LINES+1
                echo "$Line"    # Display first few lines on screen
            elif [[ $LINES -lt $(($MAX*2)) ]]; then
                LINES=LINES+1   # Count the lines for a little longer
                echo -n "."     # Reduce line output to single dot
            else
                echo -n "."     # Reduce line output to single dot
            fi
        done
        echo ""     # Finish with the dots
        # Tail last few lines, not found in head and not more then max
        if [[ $LINES -gt $MAX ]]; then
            tail -n $(($LINES-$MAX)) "$FullLogFile"
        fi
    }
}
```

Use it in a script, load it to current shell or put it in .bash_profile to be loaded on user session.

Usage examples: `cat /var/log/messages | limit_output` or `./configure | limit_output`

The function will read the standard input, save it to a log file, display the first MAX lines, then reduce each line to a single dot (.) on screen, then finally display the last MAX lines (or less if output was shorter then MAX*2).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current **incomplete** solution which for convenience is demonstrating processing a 10 lines output and that will (hopefully) limit the output to first 2 lines and last two lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

seq 10 | tee >(gzip --stdout >output.log.gz) | tail -n2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I use to achieve this is:

`./configure | tee output.log | head -n 5; tail -n 2 output.log`

What this does is:

1. Write the complete output to a filed called `output.log` using `tee`
2. Only print the first 5 lines using `head -n`
3. In the end print the last two lines from the written `output.log` using `tail -n`